# How to extract all files at once in folders from a tar.gz file

Tags: bash

I have a tar.gz file which includes 2 tar files and each tar file includes several folders and subfolders that include my required files.
I want to extract the final files from those subfolders in a directory.
I know I can use something like tar -xzvf but finally, it gives me all the folders and subfolders and the files I needed in those subfolders.

Example file:

file.tar.gz: this file contains 1.tar and 2.tar. 1.tar contains folder1, folder2, ..., folder100. and 2.tar contains foldera, folderb, ..., folderz. My text files are in these subfolders.

I want to extract all of my text files in a user-defined directory without extracting subfolders. my_dir/*.txt

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: `tar -zOxf file.tar.gz 1.tar | tar x --strip-components 1`

Comment: Thank you so much @WilliamPursell